# SpotBugs Maven Plugin - Multimodule Configuration

Tags: java, maven, spotbugs

I would like to enable the SpotBugs Maven Plugin on my multimodule project.

There is a [documentation on the official homepage](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html) for that, but the proposed project structure put's all existing modules inside a separate directory called `whiz-progs`:

```
whizbang
|-- pom.xml
|-- ...
|-- whiz-progs
    |-- pom.xml
    |-- core
    |-- gui
    |-- jmx
```

Is there a way to run Spotbugs on the modules `core`, `gui` and `jmx` while keeping them on the root level of the project? Kinda like in the [PMD multi module configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html)?